# Continuity of the Lebesgue measure w.r.t the Hausdorff metric

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, hausdorff-measure, hausdorff-distance

I have a question linked to [Interplay of Hausdorff metric and Lebesgue measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339102/interplay-of-hausdorff-metric-and-lebesgue-measure). Let us denote as $\mathcal K(\mathbb{R}^n)$ the space of compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ endowed with the Hausdorff metric $\rho$ and let $\lambda$ be the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$. I want to know if there are (sufficient) conditions under which the measure $\lambda$ is continuous w.r.t. $\rho$, that is
$$
\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\rho(K, K_k)=0\qquad\Rightarrow\qquad \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\lambda(K_k)=\lambda(K).
$$
I tried to search it in the books *Fractal geometry* by Kenneth Falconer and *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems* by Ambrosio, Fusco and Pallara but I did not find anything. In the second book it is written that, in the case $n=2$, the Hausdorff measure (which is a rescaling of the usual $\lambda$ on $\mathbb R^n$) is lower-semicontinuous w.r.t. the Hausdorff metric along sequences satisfying a suitable uniform concentration property, but this is not what I am looking for.

Some help? Do you have some references?

Comment: You probably need some very strong topological conditions on the sets $K_k$ in order for this to hold. For instance, you might need each $K_k$ to be the closure of its interior. If you don't have that, then you can easily get weird things happening like $K_k$ converging to $K$ in the Hausdorff metric but their measures converge to $0$. You can probably even get them to converge to anything you like, or not converge at all.

Comment: Definitely doesn't hold in general. Basically what goes wrong is porosity. One way to prevent that is to impose control of the surface area. I haven't written it down but I think your conclusion  goes through if you consider for example sets whose surface has  $n-1$ Hausdorff measure bounded by some constant.

Comment: After looking at the link in your OP, it seems like even being the closures of their interior is not enough, as pointed out in the answer of user147263.

Comment: @Bananach do you have some references to find such result (or something similar)? Thank you

Comment: A quick look in some places where I recall something like this (don't have time for more right now) produced: Lemma 3.6 on p. 207 of [*Invariants for quasisymmetric, quasimöbius and bilipschitz maps*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02796123) by Jussi Väisälä (see bottom of p. 205 for definition of $K^n)$ and Theorem 1 on p. 56 of my conference talk *Very porous sets and very equiporous sets* in **Real Analysis Exchange**, 24th Summer Symposium Conference Reports, May 2000, pp. 53-58.

Comment: Perhaps also ask [Timothy H. Steele](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/MRAuthorID/357054), as I think I recall seeing at least one result like this in a paper by him. (Feel free to say that I suggested sending him an email about this.)

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Claim: If the upper Minkowski dimension of $\partial K$ is strictly less than $n$ then $\rho(K,K_k)\to0$ implies $\lambda(K_k)\to \lambda(K)$.

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $k_0$ such that $\rho(K,K_k)<\epsilon$ for all $k>k_0$. Let $D_k$ be the symmetric difference between $K$ and $K_k$. Then $D_k\subset (\partial K)_{\epsilon}$. Let $d$ be the upper Minkowski dimension of $\partial K$, let $d<d'<n$,  and let $(B_{i,\epsilon})_{i=1} ^{N}$ be a collection of $N\leq \epsilon^{-d'}$ (*) balls of diameter $\epsilon$ such that $\partial K\subset \bigcup_{i}B_{i,\epsilon}$. Then
$$
(\partial K)_{\epsilon}\subset \bigcup_{i}B_{i,2\epsilon}
$$
and therefore
$$
\lambda(D_k)\leq \lambda((\partial K)_{\epsilon}) \leq N (2\epsilon)^{n}\leq 2^n\epsilon^{n-d'}\to 0
$$

(*) By the definition of the Minkowski dimension, for any $d'>d$ there exists $\epsilon_0>0$ such that $N_{\epsilon}<\epsilon^{-d'}$ is possible for all $\epsilon<\epsilon_0$.

Comment: What do you mean with $(\partial K)_{\epsilon}$?

Comment: All points within $\epsilon$ distance of the boundary of $K$

Comment: Last question! Why $N\leq C\epsilon^{-d}$?

Comment: That's almost the definition of the [Minkowski dimension](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension )
   To be precise I should have written $\leq \epsilon^{-(d+\delta)}$ but it's probably best if you just work out the details yourself to the level you need

Comment: @Redeldio Fixed the answer a bit

Comment: There's a problem. I think that in general $D_k\subset(\partial K)_{\epsilon}$ is not true. But maybe assuming that the sets are convex, this holds. What do you think? Thank you!

Comment: I think it is true in general